SwiftUI Why navigationTitle does not scroll with List
There is a toolbar button to change the viewStyle in ContentView.
When the viewStyle is changed, MyPage will regenerate the List based on the viewStyle. However, after generation, the distance between this List and the navigationTitle will automatically increase. Additionally, the navigationTitle originally scrolled with the List, but after changing the viewStyle, it will remain stationary.
What went wrong?
Thanks.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View  {
    @State private var viewStyle: ViewStyle = .bold
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                MyPage(viewStyle: $viewStyle)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Today", systemImage: "1.square.fill")
                    }
                    .tag(0)
            }
            .navigationTitle("title")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        viewStyle = viewStyle.next
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct MyPage: View {
    @Binding var viewStyle: ViewStyle
    
    var body: some View {
        switch viewStyle {
        case .bold:
            List{
                ForEach(0..<4, id: \.self){ index in
                    VStack{
                        Label("bold", systemImage: "pencil")
                    }
                }
            }
        default:
            List{
                ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self){ index in
                    VStack{
                        Label("italic", systemImage: "pencil")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
enum ViewStyle{
    case bold
    case italic
    var next: ViewStyle{
        switch self {
        case .bold: return .italic
        case .italic: return .bold
        }
    }
}


Note, NavigationView is deprecated, you should use NavigationStack and
TabView should be at the top containing NavigationStack.

There's no clear reason why you use TabView the way you use it. By removing it everything works fine.

TabView should always be at the top. Each tab needs its own NavigationStack/View

This happens when you replace the List. Try keeping the List and just replace the content:
struct MyPage: View {
    @Binding var viewStyle: ViewStyle

    var body: some View {
        List { //  Move this out here
            switch viewStyle {
            case .bold:
                ForEach(0..<4, id: \.self){ index in
                    VStack{
                        Label("bold", systemImage: "pencil")
                    }
                }
            default:
                ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self){ index in
                    VStack{
                        Label("italic", systemImage: "pencil")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

✅ Thats it!

 More enhancements:
Always try to minimize changes to prevent unexpected rendering and behavior. For example, here you could have just changed the title and count instead of the whole list! Something roughly like this:
struct MyPage: View {
    @Binding var viewStyle: ViewStyle
    var range: Range<Int> {
        switch viewStyle {
        case .bold: (0..<4)
        default: (0..<3)
        }
    }
    var title: LocalizedStringKey {
        switch viewStyle {
        case .bold: "bold"
        default: "italic"
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(range, id: \.self) { index in
                VStack {
                    Label(title, systemImage: "pencil")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

